# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-android

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Connection refused: connect
 I am using appium and selenium for android automation testing I am using selenium, Gson, appium and real device for testing when I r when I execute my code system shows me exception like that anyone can help regarding this problem I am working on issue from last two days but I am not getting any kind of help ....appium server starts correctly below is  the description of my envirnment..

1. Window 7 64
2. exclpise
3. GSON
4. Appium [ForWindows_1_4_16_1]
5. Real device [galaxy s4]
6. selenium
7. Junit

   ```
   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Connection refused: connect
   Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:14.666Z'
   System info: host: 'MACPK-WKS-0066', ip: '192.168.8.27', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
   Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.lambda$2(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:141)
       at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Unknown Source)
       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:140)
       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:77)
       at com.macrosoft.CherryPick.selendroidTest.test1(selendroidTest.java:61)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:138)
       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:86)
       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:129)
   ```

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error when I forgot to start the Appium server first. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade your version of Chrome driver (AndroidDriver?) I have the same problem with Chrome 64 and downgrade to 62 fixed this problem.